# How to resolve environment exceptions in Python?

Tags: python, exception, pytorch, anaconda, recurrent-neural-network

I wrote a simple RNN-model in PyCharm using PyTorch (tried Anaconda as well) with the goal to do a binary prediction and I get many exceptions that don't seem to directly be linked to my code:

```
File ...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py" in run_code 
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "<ipython-input-2-f0846d68ed71>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:\\ ...myRNN.py', args=['... train.fasta'], 
wdir='C:...\\PycharmProjects\\RnnProject')

  File ...Documents\PyCharm 2023.1.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py line 198, in runfile
   pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  
# execute the script
   
 ... Documents\PyCharm 2023.1.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)

...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           
  ... \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 810, in forward
    self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
```

Can someone help me & say what I can do in order to get rid of them? Thank you!

### I want to compile my source code without environment specific exceptions.

Even after the first line of code, I get the following exceptions, it must be something basically wrong with my environment settings I guess?

```
file_path = sys.argv[1]
```

After running only this line, I get:

```
File ...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3508, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "<ipython-input-2-f0846d68ed71>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('...myRNN.py', args=['...\\Downloads\\train_set.fasta'], wdir='... ')

File ...\Documents\PyCharm2023.1.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\
_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)
```

### My PyTorch version: 2.0.1+cpu
Python-Version: 3.11.4

The whole code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, train_test_split
import sys


# Load dataset(fasta file) and extract sequences and labels
file_path = sys.argv[1]


def load_fasta_file(input_file):
    data = []

    with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        i = 0
        while i < len(lines):
            if lines[i].startswith('>'):
                header_parts = lines[i].strip().split('|')
                label = header_parts[2]  # Extract "Type" as label
                i += 1
                sequence = lines[i].strip()
                i += 1
                data.append((sequence, label))
            else:
                i += 1
        return data


class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.amino_to_index = amino_to_index

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        sequences, labels = self.data[index]
        encoding = [amino_to_index[amino] for amino in sequences]
        encoding = torch.tensor(encoding, dtype=torch.long)
        return encoding, 1 if labels == "SP" else 0
     


data = load_fasta_file(file_path)
# Splitting in training- and test-dataset
#sequences = [seq for seq, label in data]
#labels = [label for seq, label in data]
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2,random_state=42)


# Create a Dictionary to identify amino acids
amino_acids = "ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY"  
amino_to_index = {amino: index for index, amino in enumerate(amino_acids)}

# Create dataset objects
train_dataset = CustomDataset(train_data)
test_dataset = CustomDataset(test_data) 


# Split dataset in training- and test-set
#train_size = int(0.8 * len(data))
#train_data = data[:train_size]
#test_data = data[train_size:]

# Create dataset objects
train_dataset = CustomDataset(train_data)
test_dataset = CustomDataset(test_data)

# Use Dataloader for Batching and loading the data
batch_size = 32
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)  


# Define LSTM-Model with two layers
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.lstm1 = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, batch_first=True, num_layers=2)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        out, _ = self.lstm1(x)
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out


# Hyperparameter
input_size = len(amino_acids)
hidden_size = 100
output_size = 1
learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 50


# Initialise weights
def init_weights(m):
    if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(m.weight)
        m.bias.data.fill_(0.01)


# Cross-Validation
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
fold_accuracies = []

for fold, (train_index, valid_index) in enumerate(skf.split(train_data, [label for _, label in train_data])):
    train_fold = [train_data[i] for i in train_index]
    valid_fold = [train_data[i] for i in valid_index]

    train_dataset_fold = CustomDataset(train_fold)
    valid_dataset_fold = CustomDataset(valid_fold)

    train_loader_fold = DataLoader(train_dataset_fold, batch_size=batch_size) #,shuffle=True
    valid_loader_fold = DataLoader(valid_dataset_fold, batch_size=batch_size)

    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


    # Initialise the model and optimizer (Gradient Descent)
    model = LSTMModel(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)
    model.apply(init_weights)  # Initialise weights of the model
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()  # Binary Cross-Entropy Loss


# Training loop
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        model.train()
        for batch_X, batch_Y in train_loader_fold:
            batch_X = batch_X.to(device) # move data to device
            batch_Y = batch_Y.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(batch_X)
            loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(), batch_Y.float())
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

#Validation loop
        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            val_loss = 0.0
            correct = 0
            total = 0
            for batch_X, batch_Y in valid_loader_fold:
                batch_X = batch_X.to(device)
                outputs = model(batch_X)
                loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(), batch_Y.float())
                val_loss += loss.item()

                predicted = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(outputs))
                total += batch_Y.size(0)
                correct += (predicted == batch_Y).sum().item()

        accuracy = correct / total
        print(
            f"Fold [{fold + 1}/5], Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{epochs}], Validation Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, Accuracy: {accuracy:.4f}")

#print the average accuracy across all folds
fold_accuracies.append(accuracy)
avg_accuracy = sum(fold_accuracies)/5
print(f"Average Validation Accuracy across all folds:{avg_accuracy: .4f}")
```

The whole traceback I get:

```
C:\Users\mp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:\Users\mp\PycharmProjects\TutoriumPython\myRNN.py C:\Users\mp\Downloads\train_set.fasta 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mp\PycharmProjects\TutoriumPython\myRNN.py", line 154, in <module>
    outputs = model(batch_X)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mp\PycharmProjects\TutoriumPython\myRNN.py", line 103, in forward
    out, _ = self.lstm1(x)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 810, in forward
    self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
  File "C:\Users\mp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 730, in check_forward_args
    self.check_input(input, batch_sizes)
  File "C:\Users\mp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\rnn.py", line 218, in check_input
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected 20, got 70

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Two of those exceptions have to do with my code directly as I see, but I am confused about the other ones... and thank you for your help!

Comment: Please post the code that is producing the error (reduced to a mwe) and how you run your code. Also include the version of pytorch you use

Comment: I just edited my comment, the problem is that even after the first line I get those Exceptions. I also copied the source code and pasted it in another project and now I get only 7 exceptions instead of 11...

Comment: The bottom code cannot cause the below exception. Don't know how you are running it, but pycharm is still executing `myRNN.py`, notice the `runfile('...myRNN.py'`. Please post the **FULL** traceback, don't shorten it. Post your code as well

Comment: Your issue is `input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected 20, got 70`, you have a mismatch in the input size that you have defined and the data you actually provide.

Comment: `I get many exceptions that don't seem to directly be linked to my code` -> they are directly caused by your code

Comment: Besides what FlyingTeller is saying, I recommend that you run your code through a notebook in smaller chunks (eg: Jupyter) as it's easier to see what part of the code is causing you issues, as opposed of expecting the IDE/terminal to give you a very nice detail of your issue. And I do recommend that you first spend more time writting basic python code and exception handling, than trying to run something very complicated without a good base on the language, the IDE and the library in question

Comment: As this is for data science, the code depends a lot on the input data to better identify the issue